# Listar informações de objetos inseridos em uma LinkedList

Tags: java, lista, fila

Estou implementando um exercício solicitado em aula referente a inserção de objetos em uma LinkedList (fila), porém não sei como realizar a impressão das informações dos objetos na tela.

Seguem as classes desenvolvidas:

```
package classes;

public class Animal {
    private int id_animal;
    private int idade;
    private String raca;

    public int getId_animal() {
        return id_animal;
    }
    public void setId_animal(int id_animal) {
        this.id_animal = id_animal;
    }
    public int getIdade() {
        return idade;
    }
    public void setIdade(int idade) {
        this.idade = idade;
    }
    public String getRaca() {
        return raca;
    }
    public void setRaca(String raca) {
        this.raca = raca;
    }

}
```

---

```
package classes;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class FilaAnimais {

    private List<Animal> animais = new LinkedList<Animal>();

    public void insere(Animal animal) {
        this.animais.add(animal);
    }

    public Animal remove() {
        return this.animais.remove(0);
    }

    public boolean vazia() {
        return this.animais.size() == 0;
    }
}
```

---

```
package classes;

public class TesteFila {

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        FilaAnimais filaAnimais = new FilaAnimais

        Animal animal = new Animal();
        animal.setId_animal(0);
        animal.setIdade(2);
        animal.setRaca("Pinscher");
        filaAnimais.insere(animal);

    }
}
```

Gostaria de saber como imprimir na tela as informações dos objetos que eu inseri nessa fila.

Answer (score 0):

Bom Dia,

Você pode fazer desta forma:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class FilaAnimais {

    private List<Animal> animais = new LinkedList<Animal>();

    public void insere(Animal animal) {
        this.animais.add(animal);
    }

    public Animal remove() {
        return this.animais.remove(0);
    }

    public boolean vazia() {
        return this.animais.size() == 0;
    }


    public void imprime() {
        for(Animal animal : this.animais){
            System.out.println(animal.getRaca());
        }
    }

    public void imprimeJavaOito() {
        this.animais.forEach(animal -> System.out.println(animal.getRaca()));
    }
}



public class TestaFila {
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        FilaAnimais filaAnimais = new FilaAnimais();

        Animal animal = new Animal();
        animal.setId_animal(0);
        animal.setIdade(2);
        animal.setRaca("Pinscher");
        filaAnimais.insere(animal);

        filaAnimais.imprime();

        filaAnimais.imprimeJavaOito();

    }

}
```